# Default file type supported by IHS web server

Tags: ihs

We earlier used IIS web server. To redirect some URLs ending with .asp, we created a directory structure based on URL's to be redirected; wrote VB script in .asp files to redirect present page to desired page and placed these .asp files in appropriate directories. Finally copied this directory structure to the docroot of IIS webserver.

Due to some reasons, we had to switch to IHS web server. As IHS does not support .asp files, we can't use same directory structure having .asp files to redirect our URLs.

Please let me know the default file type that is supported by IHS webserver (as the default filetype supported in IHS is .asp).

Thanks in advance!
SK

Answer (score 2):

There's no such notion of a "default file type" --  in IIS "asp" is parsed by the server.  In IHS or Apache, you should do you redirects with explicit server configuration such as Redirect, RedirectMatch, or mod_rewrite.

If you're already using something like PHP, you might find it convenient to sprinkle redirects in server-parsed PHP files but that's generally unwise.